# TypeError: Users.create is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, typeerror

My code was working fine. I added some new functions for login and it  broke it. So I removed the code. This is the original format, but the error still remains,  *create function of the user service is not a function*. I have read through many questions on the topic but none of the answers helped.

**UserController**

```
todoApp.controller('UserController', ['Users','$scope', function UserController(Users, $scope) {
    console.log("in user controller");

    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.submitting = false;
    $scope.submitted = false;
    $scope.has_error = false;

    console.log($scope.formModel);
    $scope.createUser = function() {
        if(!$scope.registerForm.$valid) {
            return;
        }
        Users.create($scope.formModel)
        .success(function(data){

            $scope.submitting = false;
            $scope.submitted = true;
            $scope.has_error = false;
            $scope.formModel = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
            $scope.users.push(data);
            console.log(":)");
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(":(");
            $scope.submitting = false;
            $scope.submitted = false;
            $scope.has_error = true;
        });


    };

}]);
```

**user.sevice.js**

```
todoApp.factory('Users', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('/api/users');
        },

        create: function(userData) {
            console.log(userData);
            return $http.post('/api/users', userData);
        },

        delete: function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/users/' + id);
        },

        update: function(userData) {
            return $http.put('/api/users/' + userData.id, userData);
            console.log(userData);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**register.html**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row main"  ng-controller="UserController">
        <div class="main-login main-center">
        <h5>Sign up once for instant access.</h5>
            <form name="registerForm" ng-submit="createUser()"
                novalidate="novalidate"
                ng-hide="submitted" >

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="formModel.name"
                                id="name"  
                                placeholder="Enter your Name"
                                required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your Email</label>
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="email" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="formModel.email"
                                id="email"  
                                placeholder="Enter your Email"
                                required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="formModel.username"
                                id="username"  
                                placeholder="Enter your Username"
                                required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                ng-model="formModel.password" 
                                id="password"  
                                placeholder="Enter your Password"
                                required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <label for="confirm" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" 
                            class="form-control" 
                            name="confirm" 
                            id="confirm"  
                            placeholder="Confirm your Password"
                            required="required" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" >
                    <label for="type" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">User Type</label >
                    <div class="cols-sm-10">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-university" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <select id="type"
                                        class="form-control"
                                        ng-model="formModel.role"
                                        required="required" >
                            <option value="" >Please Choose</option >
                            <option value="1" >Lecturer</option >
                            <option value="2" >Student</option >
                        </select >
                    </div>
                </div >
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"
                            ladda="submitting"
                            data-style="expand-right"
                                type="submit">
                        <span ng-show="submitting">Registering</span>
                        <span ng-show="!submitting">Register</span>
                    </button>
                </div>        
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return callback with value rather than returning HTTP raw promise from server. Try this

**Service**

```
create: function(userData, callback) {
      $http.post('/api/users', userData).then(function (res) {
            return callback(res.data); 
      }, 'error')
},
```

**Controller**

// Success is deprecated for Angular 1.5 >

// Success code return from server (This is not the true error code likes 404 and 500. This is just the code you gave from server) - let say the server return json format for success - {code: '0000', remark: 'Success'} and error - {code: '9999', remark: 'Success'} . This is depend on your server. This is what i'm do in my previous project

```
 $scope.createUser = function() {
    if(!$scope.registerForm.$valid) {
        return;
    }
    Users.create($scope.formModel, function (res) {
         switch (res.code) {
           case '0000':
               $scope.submitting = false;
               $scope.submitted = true;
               $scope.has_error = false;
               $scope.formModel = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
               $scope.users.push(data);
        console.log(":)");
               break;
          case '9999': 
                console.log(":(");
                $scope.submitting = false;
                 $scope.submitted = false;
                $scope.has_error = true;
                console.log('error');
               break;
      }
    });
};
```

Let say your server return no error code and only just data. You can do it like this

```
 $scope.createUser = function() {
    if(!$scope.registerForm.$valid) {
        return;
    }
    Users.create($scope.formModel, function (res) {
        if (res !== undefined) {          
               $scope.submitting = false;
               $scope.submitted = true;
               $scope.has_error = false;
               $scope.formModel = {}; // clear the form so our user is ready to enter another
               $scope.users.push(data);
        } else {
                console.log(":(");
                $scope.submitting = false;
                 $scope.submitted = false;
                $scope.has_error = true;
                console.log('error');
       }
      }
    });
```

Comment: That worked a treat. Sorry for not replying till now, but I was away from computer since I asked the question. On another note should the case 'xxxx' be filled with http response numbers like 403 or 200 for success?

Comment: Thats a case for success, in other word for http response 200 only. You can catch another http error code in 'error' before closing http post.

Comment: I am a little confused as to what the case '0000' and case '9999' do. Does it mean it catches any http response greater than 0000 and less than 9999?

Comment: I just updated my answer above. Feel free to clarify your confusion.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now.

Answer (score -1):

if the above-provided code is correct then there is no issue in the code.
you may be missing references.
Check my plunker. Your code makes the calls till the api.

Console window of my plunk

```
in user controller
VM413 app.js:11 Object {}__proto__: Object
VM413 app.js:13 create called!!
VM413 app.js:45 create method on factory called!!
VM413 app.js:46 Object {name: "Kalyan", email: "test@test.com", username: "tee", password: "tet", role: "1"}
VM411 angular.min.js:105 POST https://run.plnkr.co/api/users 400 ()
```

[Click here to see my plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zpM2Bf?p=preview)

Comment: that worked for sure in your plunker. What references would be referring too.